# Can Bootstrap 5 read the content of an excel table and display it inside an HTML table?

Tags: html, excel, bootstrap-4

I have searched high and low on the internet and am having no luck finding a direct answer. I have created an html page that utilizes Bootstrap tables. Right now I have my table content written directly into the HTML. It was recommended to me that I remove the table content from the HTML and instead find a way for the HTML to 'read' an external tabular file (like .xlxs) and have it display on the HTML page inside a div. Is there something in the Bootstrap library that could help me to do this. I am very new to things like JavaScrip and JQuery so if I had to code it directly, the script would need to be as simple as possible. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks!

I also have an added challenge where one of the table columns provides hyperlinks. I found some code examples online that could read an excel file and display the content as an html table but, it was only as text. The code examples also always required user input to pick an excel file. I instead am trying to determine if there is also someway for me to use an onload function to get the excel to load immediately when the page is opened to display the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just embed the Excel sheet from OneDrive? Go to your Excel document in OneDrive then click `File` > `Share` > `Embed`. Select your options and then it will provide an embed code that you can plop on your page to show the document in an iframe.

More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-onedrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, I don't think that is an option for my organization. I also need to ensure the content is not editable for users.